# How can I build asset files including blank?

Tags: android, android-build, ninja

I made a test android application. It had an 'asset' folder with a file including black. The filename is "test sample".
When I run aosp build, I got an error as below.
This application could make an apk on Android Studio successfully.
However, I need to build it to include it in the system image.
How can I build asset files including blank?

**FAILED: ninja: 'packages/apps/Test/assets/sample', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/Test_intermediates/src/R.stamp', missing and no known rule to make it
15:29:43 ninja failed with: exit status 1**

Comment: What is 'blank'?

Comment: The filename has space character like "test sample".

Comment: Well ... adapt your subject and the text of your post then.